# Dynamically initialise view controllers in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, initialization

This question relates to dynamically initializing different view controllers based on runtime options. Basically, When the app starts up, a web service sends a piece of XML/JSON down to define user preferences etc.

We need to determine which view controller is shown to the user next, based on these variables. So we have a class which asks certain questions (which features are turned on/off etc), and then we need to be able to return a class or initialize a class based on this. Since I do not want to import every view controller header in each view controller, how do I initialize a class using some method such as:

```
 [[self nextClassManager] getNextClass];
```

thanks

Comment: `id vc = [[[self nextClassManager] getNextClass] alloc] init];`

Comment: What would the 'getNextClass' method header look like? i.e. what type would it return?

Comment: `Class` is the return type.

Comment: how do you return the view controller in this method? getting an incompatible type from 'viewcontroller_strong' to Class

Comment: So do you know how to generate a class dynamically? E. g. do you know there's an `NSClassFromString()` function in Foundation?

Comment: In the sniplet that H2CO3 suggetst you do not retun an instance within `getNextClass`but just the class. If `MyViewController` is one of the classes that you could return then use `return [MyViewController class]`. `class` works on instances and classes alike. Instead of `id` you could use the closest common superclass of all the viewcontrollers.

Comment: Do you need to initialise anything in the return method? I am calling:

     DailyChecksViewController *test;
    NSString *className = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", NSStringFromClass(test.class)];
    NSLog(@"%@", className);
    
    NSArray *returnArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:test.class, className, nil];

It is returning null for both the class and the className (string)

Answer (score 0):

I use something similar to open a view controller from server command, according to the controller class name:

```
- (void)openViewController:(NSString *)theControllerClassName {
    Class theControllerClass = NSClassFromString(theControllerClassName);
    if (theControllerClass && [theControllerClass isSubclassOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
        UIViewController* controller = [[theControllerClass performSelector:@selector(alloc)] init];

        UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)self.tabBarController.selectedViewController;
        [nav pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
        [controller release];
    }
}
```